# Service API call blocks UI in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I have a UITableViewController and have to load a not so big amount of data on start. In my viewDidLoad, I use a different queue to send the request:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        var data = self.getStoresData()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.parseStoresData(data)
            self.resultsController = PartnerStore.getAllStores()

        });
    });
}
```

And these are the methods:

```
func getStoresData() -> [NSDictionary]
{
    var responseData = [NSDictionary]()
    self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    AppDelegate.appDelegate().httpRequestOperationManager?.GET(
        "partner_stores/",
        parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            self.tableView.reloadData();
            println("RESPONSE OBJECT IN GET PARTNER STORES: \(responseObject)") },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
            println("FAIL IN GET PARTNER STORES: \(error)") })
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    return responseData
}

func parseStoresData(storesData: [NSDictionary])
{
    for storeDict in storesData {
// just inserts a new object to CoreData
        PartnerStore.addNewStore(storeDict)
    }
}
```

The problem is (I think) that the API call is async, so the two functions in dispatch_async are executed before the data is downloaded from the server. But if I put everything in the success block of the GET call, it takes a lot of time and the whole UI is blocked. What is the best way to to the server call, without blocking the UI thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the two calls in the `dispatch_async` in `viewDidLoad` being called before your `GET` request completes; that's a problem. You also had the right idea when you said you tried putting everything in the `success` block; that's where it should go flow wise. There are a few other things that need to be moved around as well though.

One good way to go about handling UI updates is to have separate functions for your UI updates and your data fetch. Doing it that way means we'll need to pass a callback to your `getStoresData` function and then call it appropriately in your `GET` function's `success` and `error` blocks. That will let us know when the data fetch is complete so that we can finish the UI updates. We'll also want to move the dispatch to the background queue out of `viewDidLoad` and in to `getStoresData`.

So, lets pull any UI changes out of `getStoresData` and move that dispatch:

```
func getStoresData(callback: (error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        // ... do any setup ...
        AppDelegate.appDelegate().httpRequestOperationManager?.GET(
            // ... other GET parameters ...
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                var responseData = [NSDictionary]()

                // do what you need to convert responseObject to responseData
                // then...

                // NOTE: we'll dispatch the the main thread here because parseStoresData deals with CoreData.
                // This dispatch could be done in parseStoresData itself but
                // a callback function would need to be added to it as well
                // in that case.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.parseStoresData(responseData)

                    // The response has been dealt with, so call the callback
                    callback(error: nil)
                });
            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                // There was an error, so call the callback with the error object
                callback(error: error)
            }
        )
    })
}
```

Now let's make that new function to handle updating the UI so that the data updates are decoupled from the UI updates. In this function we'll first start the refresh control and call `getStoresData`. Then, when `getStoresData` finishes, update the table view and stop the refresh control.

```
func reloadData() {
    // start the refresh control on the main thread so the user knows we're updating
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    })

    // do the actual data fetch...
    // (remember this will dispatch to a background thread on its own now)
    getStoresData({
        (error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // since this callback could be called from any thread,
        // make sure to dispatch back to the main UI thread to finish the UI updates
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if let actualError = error {
                // update the UI appropriately for the error
            } else {
                // update the data in the table view and reload it
                self.resultsController = PartnerStore.getAllStores()
                self.tableView.reloadData();
            }                

            // we're done; stop the refresh control
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        })
    })
}
```

That makes your `viewDidLoad` function very simple now:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    reloadData()
}
```

This also makes it easier to implement things like pull to refresh since you can simply call `reloadData` when the user triggers the refresh instead of duplicating the UI update code all over the place.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed answer. I just have one problem - I get an `Int is not convertible to UInt` error for the 0 in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)`, which is weird, since I had no problems using it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: So the error appears, only when I make the API call inside the block, if I remove it, the error disappears. I guess the problem is somewhere in the AFNetworking source, or at least I see no other possibility.

Comment: @smeshko that certainly is odd. Did you try manually converting the `0` to a `UInt`, i.e. `UInt(0)`? You really shouldn't need to, but who knows maybe there's some esoteric rule that the compiler is following there.

Comment: So, after a few days of banging my head, turns out I just had to save the return object from the call in a variable (edited the answer with the solution). The data loads a bit faster now, but the UI is still blocked while loading (I can't change tabs or go back to the previous view for example). Also, the `refreshControl` doesn't show up.